# Access a textbox declared in App.xaml (WpfNotifyIcon Tooltip) from another window

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, notifyicon

I am using WpfNotifyIcon, I have declared it as a resource like this:

```
<Application x:Class="NotifyIconScratchPad2.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:tb="http://www.hardcodet.net/taskbar" 
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <tb:TaskbarIcon x:Key="MyNotifyIcon" IconSource="Icons/stopwatch_start.ico" ToolTipText="Hello world" >
            <tb:TaskbarIcon.TrayToolTip>
                <TextBlock x:Name="ChangeThis" Text="Hello world"  />
            </tb:TaskbarIcon.TrayToolTip>
            </tb:TaskbarIcon>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

To use this, I declare it in `MainWindow.xaml.cs`:

```
    public TaskbarIcon tb;
    public Window1 myWindow;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        tb = (TaskbarIcon) FindResource("MyNotifyIcon");
    }
```

How can I access the textbox `ChangeThis` from another window?

Comment: I couldn't find the answer. I ended up declaring the notifyIcon in the Window itself and then accessing the TextBlock from there.

Answer (score 0):

The ultimate answer is setting up an event to do so.

The [Model-View-View Model](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/165368/WPF-MVVM-Quick-Start-Tutorial) pattern is a good way to accomplish this.

Basically, you have a class that implements the [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) interface and a two-way [data binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750612.aspx) between both text boxes and the data source.

Comment: I am not familiar with MVVM, is there a way around it? Can you point me towards some sample code? Do I have to implement INotifyProperty in App.xaml.cs?

Comment: It's a different way of working with Windows. I guess you're using the Code Behind file for most of your logic?

Comment: Yes, I am using code behind file. How would I do it if I was using data binding? Thanks for answering.

Comment: I'll get an example together soon.

Answer (score 0):

you can use FindName method:

```
 TextBox txtToChange= tb.FindName("txt_ChangeThis") as TextBox;
```

Comment: When I do `TextBlock textBlock = tb.FindName("ChangeThis") as TextBlock;`, I am getting `null` back. It isn't working. Anything else  I can do?